# Tag <br/> doesnt work on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, text

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
    $('#id').text("this is my text " + "<br/>");
});
```

**This is my jquery code. When I click the button `mybutton` the text should change into this. My problem now is the `<br/>` tag doesn't work on it. Is there any other way for this? Thanks.**

Comment: show the html...what element has the id `id`?is it an input?if it is an input do `$('#id').val("this is my text " + "<br/>")`

Comment: Side-note: XHTML isn't all it was cracked up to be. Feel free to just use `<br>`.

Answer (score 5):

`.text()` converts the tags into html entities. Use `.html()`

```
$('#id').html("this is my text " + "<br/>");
```

This is covered in the docs, if you desire to read them before attempting to use jQuery. https://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Thank you! Very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
    $('#id').html("this is my text " + "<br/>");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, the `text()` function replaces text, and doesn't recognize markup.

To replace the inner html in JQuery, try the `html()` function instead:

```
$('#id').html("this is my text<br/>on two lines").
```

Comment: Thank you! Very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

1 . Check your jQuery include

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

2. Check your html component
If you using a input text, the right code is

```
$('#id').val("this is my text " + "<br/>");
```

If you using a block content like `<div>` or `<span>`

```
$('#id').html("this is my text " + "<br/>");
```

.text function in JQuery escape your html code

3. Try using " instead of '